# Why does "Chromium Helper EH" crash when I try to launch Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, crash

Every time I launch Chromium, a dialog box appears almost immediately telling me that "Chromium Helper EH has unexpectedly quit." Several things don't work, including the New Tab button missing the + symbol, several keyboard shortcuts don't work, and pages don't load more than halfway. What's happening and how can I fix it?

(Extra phrases to help this show up for people searching for "Google Chrome": Google Chrome Helper EH, Google Chrome crashes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that in 10.7.3, installing Chromium/Google Chrome from another account causes this bug. Simply installing it while using the account it will be used in solves the problem. Unfortunately, no other accounts can use it.

Comment: Same problem here with 10.6.8. :-(  Do you have a link for this issue?

Comment: No, I haven't been able to find it reported on any site and I haven't reported it myself. Feel free to; I'll add a link to the answer.

Comment: Maybe this one is related: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95037 Does not mention multiple accounts, but I'll add a link to this discussion there.